# Emailing from Gmail using phpmailer. Login Error

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I cant seem to get my head around why i cant send emails using all sorts of mail classes in php. I know my password etc is correct.

Any one have any ideas?

I get the error:

> SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 534-5.7.14 Please
>   log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14
>   Learn more at 534 5.7.14
>   https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754
>   dm6sm8657044wib.22 - gsmtp  SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Mailer
>   Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

```
function mail1($to,$body,$subject){

    include "/libs/mailer/classes/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "lewis.morris@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "xxxxxxxx";
    $mail->SetFrom("lewis.morris@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);

    if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else{
        echo "Message has been sent";
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you using gmail's mail server?

Comment: i have managed to fix it by going to here... https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: I am using gmails to test it as i dont have hosting yet... I've taught myself PHP/HTML/CSS from scratch in the last month or so.

http://86.24.143.201/home.php (still a massive WIP) what do you think

Comment: Not too bad for your first project. My first website was... interesting, let's say. Yea.

Comment: Thanks mate, if any one has any good resources for PHP I would appreciate it

Answer (score 9):

This link always help me for any kind of login problem into gmail from my application. Try this may it can helps you...

Here, trun on logging for less secure apps: https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security/lesssecureapps

Here, just click continue... https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

And check here is there any logging to your account: https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?hl=en&pli=1

And, run your code..

Answer (score 0):

1. Update PHPMailer to latest version
   OR
2. Add 'tls' before 'smtp.gmail.com'

For #2 use bellow Code

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = "tls://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, its appreciated !! :) @Sakil Alam, but you are 5 years too late

Comment: Yeah I know. I just posted to let people know who are searching for this issue. I was facing the issue so thought if it help them.